# TypeError: 'values' is not ordered, please explicitly specify the categories order by passing in a categories argument

Tags: python, sorting

```
> df.info()

0   Date              12554 non-null  datetime64[ns]
3   Hour              12554 non-null  object
```

I have two variables as Date and Hour. I want to create a new variable of type datetime with these two variables and sort it. I used the following codes for this, but I am getting the following Type Error.

```
df["DATETIME"] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'].astype(str) + " " + df['Hour'].astype(str))

df.sort_values(by='DATETIME', inplace=True)
```

**TypeError: 'values' is not ordered, please explicitly specify the categories order by passing in a categories argument.**

The format of my values that I want to sort is as follows. ;

```
2022-07-27 16:47:00
```

Thank you!

Comment: try instead sorting by date then time, ```df.sort_values(by=["Date", "Time"])```. this might not work since the type of ```Time``` is object not datetime. if it doesn't work, add your output for ```df.info()``` including your datetime col. It would also help to have some example data in the same format as the data you're using

Comment: @smcrowley hello first of all thank you for the answer, The reason I got the error was an error in excel where the data was saved.